# function in a function with double reference

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to convert lower case letters to upper case by passing character array as argument. I wrote 'toUpper' method inside 'htoi' method as you can see in the code and I resorted to use double reference argument for 'toUpper' method, and it's giving me errors when accessing the data in the array. When I declare 'toUppper' method with single reference argument in the main, it works fine. I don't need solutions but I just want to know why it doesn't work.. please help....

```
#include <stdio.h>

void toUpper(char **s);

int htoi(char s[]) {
    int i, n;
    n = 0;

    toUpper(s);//<--error here

    for (i = 0; (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') ||(s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'F'); ++i) {
        n = 16 * n + determine(s, i);//converting
    }
    return n;
}

void toUpper(char** s) {
    for (int i = 0; **(s + i) != '\0' ; ++i) {//traverse until null value
        if (**(s + i) >= 'a' && **(s + i) <= 'f') {
            **(s + i) = **(s + i) - ('a' - 'A');//convert character to upper case if true
        }
    }
}

int determine(char hexNum[], int i) {

    int a;

    if (*(hexNum+i) >= 'A') {
        a = (*(hexNum+i) - 'A' + 10);
        return a;
    }
    else if(*(hexNum + i) <= '9'){
        a = (*(hexNum + i) - '0');
        return a;
    }
}

main() {
    int a;
    int i = 0;
    char s[] = "ba";


    a = htoi(s);
    printf("%d", a);

}
```

Comment: You don't need double pointer.  Just replace ** with *.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you don't need this solution...

Comment: Maybe this will work *((*s) + i) ? I didn't tested.

Comment: s is pointer to pointer to char. What is s + i ? Think about it.

Comment: "*I resorted to use double reference argument for 'toUpper' method*" Why?

Comment: ".. it's giving me errors .." What errors?

Comment: I am fairy new to programming so I thought passing a pointer argument in a function using a pointer local to that function (like s[ ]) ) meant that you had to use double reference. I must have written something wrong like a single letter when testing it with single reference. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `htoi` , the type of `s` is `char*`, but the argument of `toUpper` is `char**`, you should use like `toUpper(&s);`
2. Before use `determine`, you need declare or define it.
3. `determine` need add a `return`

The follow code could work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void toUpper(char *s);
int determine(char hexNum[], int i);

int htoi(char s[]) {
    int i, n;
    n = 0;

    toUpper(s);//<--error here

    for (i = 0; (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') ||(s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'F'); ++i) {
        n = 16 * n + determine(s, i);//converting
    }
    return n;
}

void toUpper(char* s) {
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i) {//traverse until null value
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'f') {
            s[i] = s[i] - ('a' - 'A');//convert character to upper case if true
        }
    }
}

int determine(char hexNum[], int i) {

    int a;

    if (*(hexNum+i) >= 'A') {
        a = (*(hexNum+i) - 'A' + 10);
        return a;
    }
    else if(*(hexNum + i) <= '9'){
        a = (*(hexNum + i) - '0');
        return a;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int a;
    char s[] = "ba";

    a = htoi(s);
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying and pointing out terrible coding conventions I wrote, I figured out I didn't have to use double reference after looking at the comments. Weird thing is I still get errors when I pass it as &s, when in theory it should have worked.

Comment: @res0bj50 I fixed the `toUpper` function and added code to the above answer, you can test it.